# Executing python 3 scripts in a mobile app (iOS, Android)

Tags: android, python, ios, mobile

During my school internship I had to write **some python scripts** (especially files transfer scripts using sockets). But now I have to **embed and use them in computers** (Windows & MacOS) **and mobile environement** (Android & iOS). For computers it seems to no be hard since you just have to previously install Python. The problem comes with mobile apps.

I already tried to embed the interpreter while making a Qt C++ cross-platform app but it resulted with an error "io.h no such file or directory" in the pyconfig.h included by python.h.

**Since I can't write them in python (I have to make 2 native applications) and that I must use Python 3, how could I do that ?**

Thanks in advance !

PS : The purpose of this work is to facilitate file transfer between a lot of devices (even Computers <=> Phone) by using a unique script (I don't want to rewrite it for every platform)